# Differentiating between two values sent over WinSock (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, optimization, winsock

I have a C++ Server and Client running locally, they are connected through WinSock and can communicate.

I need to send two distinct kinds of updates between them (`updateA` & `updateB`).

`updateA` is a `char*` but `updateB` is an object pointer. I can not access the object that `updateB` points to (though I know that it is some form of string/char - all I know is its length).

Currently, I send both of these variables between Server and Client the same way, but they can be sent in any order depending on circumstances:

```
iResult = send( this->ClientSocket, (char*)this->updateA, this->updateALength, 0 );
//check for errors etc
iResult = send( this->ClientSocket, (char*)this->*updateB, this->updateBLength, 0 );
//check for errors etc
```

But on arrival they need to be handled differently, eg:

```
int iResult = recv( this->ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0 );
if( iResult > 0 )
{
    if(is_updateA(recvbuf))
    {
        //do updateA things
    } elif (is_updateB(recvbuf)) {
        //do updateB things
    }
}
```

According to `typeid( recvbuf ).name()` both updates are of the type `char [1024]` (both cast to `char*` during the send as prior to that `updateA` is a `char const * __ptr64` and `updateB` is a `unsigned char * __ptr64`).

What would be the cleanest way to differentiate between `updateA` and `updateB`? I've considered appending some kind of tag onto the beginning of `updateA` but this does not feel like a very robust solution.

Comment: Send an extra byte? 0x00 means it's updateA. 0x01 means it's updateB. By the way your receiving code is wrong because the OS might receive a different amount of data at once than you sent.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, thanks. Btw, what is wrong with my receiving code?

Comment: I assume you are using TCP. It is a stream protocol designed for servers to send files (basically). It does not remember how many bytes you sent at one time, it joins them all together. If you send 5 bytes and then you send 6, the receiver might get all 11 at once, or they might get 5 and then 6, or 6 and then 5, or 3 and then 3 and then 3 and then 2, or any other combination.

Comment: If it works now, that's probably because there was a big gap between the two sends so the OS decided to give you the bytes it had already received instead of waiting for more bytes. But it doesn't have to do that! Tomorrow a little network hiccup might delay the first send, so they arrive at the same time and then your program gets both at once.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea - I'll look into a better way - thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @JessicaChambers the best way to deal with variable-length data is to send the data length before sending the data itself. For instance, when sending a `char*` string, send a `uint32_t` containing the string's length in bytes, then send the `char` data afterwards. The receiver can read the `uint32_t` first, allocate the specified amount of memory, and then read the `char` data into that memory. Same with objects, though that will take more work since you can't send an object as-is over a socket, you will need to send the object's data fields individually as needed

Comment: If you haven’t yet encountered the term, look up “packet” or “frame.” It’s the general idea of sending data in a structured form that tells the receiver how much data was sent and (possibly) how it’s structured.